# Finding hardcoded string in React Native (using WebStorm)

Tags: react-native, internationalization, webstorm, hardcoded

My project has a lot of hardcoded strings and they are creating a mess in translating the project.

I read about that WebStorm's inspection can find them, but I didn't find any such option in internationalization of WebStorm's code inspect. Is it hidden somewhere or are any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java | Internationalization | Hard coded strings** inspection is only available for Java, there is no such inspection for TypeScript/JavaScript.

You can try a third-party [i18n support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12981-i18n-support)  plugin - it provides a basic support for javascript internationalization; see if it works for you